# complie elasticsearch's docker-compose.yml Occurrence is a issure prompt:services.es01.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, synonym

this is  docker-compose.yml:
[this is  docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KZXM.png)

this is synonym.txt

[ente:q:r image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdo9g.png)

his is error prompt:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgqzd.png)

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/etc/docker# docker-compose stop
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.es01.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
services.es02.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: You should not post links to images that contains text, but post the text directly here.